# Why can I not ping outside my network with this configuration?

Tags: networking, ping

Ip-adres: 10.0.10.100/24
Router: 10.0.0.1
DNS: 8.8.8.8

I know it has something to do with the given ip range but I am not that familiar with networking. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to ping machines inside your network?  Are you able to ping outside your network with other machines?

Comment: Pinging inside the network does work. Just ping outside does not work.

Comment: can you please give me the complete routing table? (`ip route show`). I suspect, you messed the routing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to send ip packages from one network to another without a router doing the routing for you:

Members of network A (10.0.**10**.100/24) are limited to their IP range (10.0.10.0 - 10.0.10.255) whereas your Router is located on network B (10.0.**0**.1/??) and therefore not in the list of peers your machine can reach.

Now you have various options:

- set the network for all machines including router to 10.0.0.0/20
- change the ipadress of the router to something in 10.0.10.0/24 (i.e. 10.0.10.1)
- change the network configuration of all machines that are not in the same network as the router to match those settings of "router"

help on those steps is most probably enough text for a new question ;)

Comment: Just watched some vids on lynda.com on subnetting which helped me understand your answer. Thank you very much for explaining. You have helped me out a lot.